# How to upgrade Magento from 1.7 to 1.9

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, upgrade, updates, magento-1.9

I need to upgrade my magento store form 1.7 to 1.9. I am very new to magento, I was just wondering what is the easiest way to upgrade without breaking my website.

Thank you

Comment: You can download the latest magento from site and upload  it to the root of your current magento installation. and overrite all files it wll ask for . BUt keep one thing ion mind you must be sure that you have not edited any core file of your current magento , otherwise you will loose all your changes.

Comment: i follow all these steps but it's not working  http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/21761/magento-upgrade-from-1-7-to-1-9

Comment: are you getting any error after doing all steps

Comment: yes "There has been an error processing your request" this is the error

Comment: please check error under var/log/system.log folder

Comment: i am trying to connect with you on you G+ 
i leave  messages for you 
please can you come in any live chat ?
i am in very big trouble please help me

Comment: The most obvious answer is to not do it on your production site until you've done it on a test site!

Answer (score 1):

**Upgrade Roadmap for CE 1.9.0.1 from 1.7**

1. take a backup of current database and current 1.7 code.
2. download latest magento from the http://www.magentocommerce.com/download
3. remove all folders and files from your 1.7 code (but you should have backup somewhere) and place all folders and files from the 1.9.
4. now from your 1.7 merge your following folders into the 1.9

•   Community `app/code/community`

•   Local `app/code/local`

•   Media

•   your theme or package (`app/design/frontend/default/<your theme> or app/design/frontend/<your package>`)

•   custom folders from Skin (both for adminhtml and frontend).

•   copy your custom xml files from `app/etc/modules/` to current `app/etc/modules/`

•   any custom admin theme folder from adminhtml/default/yourtheme.

•   copy your custom folders from `adminhtml/default/default/` (1.7) to `adminhtml/default/default/` (1.9).

•   custom js files if any from `app/js/`.

5. now go to app/etc/local.xml.Edit database details there. put your database username and password and database name.
6. now check the site. it's done.

Comment: i try this many times 
but this is not helpful
anyways i update my magento with magento connect but after this there is a issue . when i try to open some other page except index it says 404 not found 
can you help me with this ?

Comment: ( Remove all folders and files from your 1.7 code )  CAN YOU PLEASE mentioned the directory path or folders or files which needs to remove.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade directly:

Admin panel -> System -> Magento Connect -> Magento Connect Manager

Check for Upgrades

Mage_All_Latest -> select Upgrade to 1.9

Uupgrade via ssh :

Commands :

1: ./mage list-upgrades

2: ./mage config-set preferred_state stable

3: ./mage upgrade-all --force (if not working thenuse 4)

4: ./mage install http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community Mage_All_Latest --force

5: php -f ./index.php

For more info, check the below link:

https://astrio.net/blog/magento-upgrade-guide/