# Magento database error

Tags: php, sql, database, magento-1.7, magento-1.9

I have a Webshop on magento. I would update it from 1.7.0.2 to 1.9.2.1.

First i tried to copy the files from 1.9 to 1.7. Didn't worked. Then i tried to delet all files, put all files from 1.9 on the server and copy all important files from 1.7. Didn't worked.

So now i complitly re-installed magento with the newest version 1.9.2.1. I set it up like the old version and used the same encryption-key. Than i thought, i could copy the old database to the new one. Bu i gives me some sql errors, that it could not find rows.

```
Error in file: "/home/sybille/web/naef2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/sql/core_setup/mysql4-data-upgrade-1.6.0.2-1.6.0.3.php" - SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'crc_string' in 'field list', query was: UPDATE `core_translate` SET `crc_string` = CRC32(`string`)

Trace:
#0 /home/sybille/web/naef2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(645): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')
#1 /home/sybille/web/naef2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(407): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('data-upgrade', '1.6.0.2', '1.6.0.6')
#2 /home/sybille/web/naef2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(286): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_upgradeData('1.6.0.2', '1.6.0.6')
#3 /home/sybille/web/naef2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(269): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyDataUpdates()
#4 /home/sybille/web/naef2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(362): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllDataUpdates()
#5 /home/sybille/web/naef2/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#6 /home/sybille/web/naef2/index.php(85): Mage::run('', 'store')
#7 {main}
```

I need your help now! :(

I'm about to fix it for 2 days and i don't come forward. Pleas help me! how can i setup the database, that it works with the new version.

Comment: I'm not familiarized with Magento DB structure, but that's why migration routines are needed. The schema could have changes (new columns, different table names, stored procedures, etc) that might compromise the entire application flow if you just copy and paste and expect it to work.

Comment: Did you searched on Magento forums about version upgrading practices, some guide on that matter? The vendor usually provides it in their docs.

Comment: i found a instruction, but it didn't worked. nothing works!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28809425/how-to-upgrade-magento-from-1-7-to-1-9

it's not working!

Comment: **What** not work? Are you receiving errors (if yes, show them to us)?  If you try to install 1.7 again, can you run it on the old DB? DO you have a backup of this?

Comment: Did you [read this](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installing_upgrade_details.html)?

Comment: Thank you so much @AlanMachado :) But how can i copy all extensions i've installed on the old magento?

Comment: yes @AlanMachado, but, all productitems aren't shown...

Comment: It can be a minor issue that Magento support community might have solutions for it (most people suffer while upgrading a scale of versions bigger than one)

Comment: Extesions are a separated issue. You'll probably have to install them all again, and see if you won't have any compatibility issues (like ext that aren't supported by your new version)